# Is a CLA necessary?

Tags: licensing, contributor, contributor-agreements

[PDF4QT](https://github.com/JakubMelka/PDF4QT/) is released under LGPL3+.

If you open a PR, the maintainer asks you to sign a [CLA](https://github.com/JakubMelka/PDF4QT/blob/master/CLA/Contribution_Licence_Agreement.pdf).

1. Is this necessary?

   My code must be released under LGPL3+ as well, otherwise I'll fail to fulfill the license obligations.

   So, by the fact that my own code is under LGPL3+, by the terms of this license, he can use in his own software.

   Is that right?
2. Is it necessary to ask also for birth date and address?

Comment: He is not required to get a CLA from you, but nothing prevents him from asking you for one, and refusing your changes if you don't want to sign one.

Comment: The Readme file in the repository gives a rationale for the CLA: “I want to have a freedom to do whatever I want with my library, without obligation to someone else.” I.e. the maintainer doesn't want to be bound by your LGPL license. A sole developer asking for a CLA is unusual, this is more often seen in projects run by companies that are dual-licensing with proprietary terms or want the freedom to relicense to a more restrictive license. For example, MongoDB was able to relicense from AGPL to the non-Open Source SSPL because it had obtained necessary rights via CLAs.

Answer (score 6):

A CLA is indeed not necessary for PDF4QT to use your contribution under the terms of the LGPL.

The main purposes of this CLA are twofold:

1. to potentially use the contribution under terms other than the LGPL in the future (see terms 2.3 - 2.5 for the perpetual, broad license you grant to the project, allowing them to relicense in the future)
2. to reduce liability for unlawful contributions or contributions encumbered in a way that can't satisfy the first purpose of the CLA (i.e., term 3.1(b) is an assertion that you have "unlimited econommic rights" to your contribution). This deflects liability for contributions that infringe some third party's copyright, or are offered under a license that isn't compatible with the LGPL (or any other license the project might employ in the future).

(I'm no lawyer but:) Especially in order to make second function of this CLA operate, I expect it can't effectively deflect liability for infringing contributions without a specific, well-known person to deflect that liability onto.

Comment: can I declare to release my code in the public domain in the PR, so he can do whatever he wants without me signing a CLA?

Comment: @robertspierre Sure, but "whatever he wants" may be nothing. If they care deeply about avoiding any copyright issues with a project, merging some code that is just declared to be in public domain in a comment is likely not in their best interests. Besides, it wouldn't really be in public domain as it is a derivative work of a LGPL-licensed work.

Comment: @robertspierre If (1) your contribution is lifted wholesale from someone else's work, or if (2) you have an employer whose contact assigns copyright control for works you produce, then your dedication to the public domain wouldn't be valid. *You* may be able to verify that neither of those apply for your case, but the project cannot to be sure of this, with any meaningful degree of legal rigor, until you assert it under a binding agreement. Many projects are prepared to accept this kind of risk from anonymous contributors; this project is not.